# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scrapy'

Tags: scrapy

```
import Scrapy


class NgaSpider(Scrapy.Spider):
    name = "NgaSpider"
    host = "http://bbs.ngacn.cc/"
    start_urls = [
        "http://bbs.ngacn.cc/thread.php?fid=406",
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        print ("response.body")
```

---

Error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scrapy'

What is going on to fix this issue？

Comment: Which OS are you using? Have you installed scrapy?

Comment: Try __import scrapy__ instead of __import Scrapy__

Comment: oh, scrapy is changed ,but still appearing with "Not found :No module named spider". So spider module is existing with another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly importing the scrapy module.

Find a simple tutorial and references from [here.](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.3/intro/overview.html)

You have to do the following changes:

```
import scrapy # Change here


class NgaSpider(scrapy.Spider): # Change here too
    name = "NgaSpider"
    host = "http://bbs.ngacn.cc/"
    start_urls = [
        "http://bbs.ngacn.cc/thread.php?fid=406",
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        print ("response.body")
```

> Assuming you are using **1.3** version of it.

To check use

`pip show scrapy`

Comment: spider module is not yet found

Comment: Please post your stacktrace in question. Show what exactly you are facing here.

Comment: Err：class NgaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'Spider'

Comment: @beango Have you named "scrapy" to any of your project files or directory?

Comment: No, do I need create files or directory for "scrapy”？

Comment: Show your full project directory structure

Comment: I try create file and directory ,great . Thanks