# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'" and "bash: scrapy: command not found" on MacOs

Tags: bash, macos, scrapy, pip, python-3.7

Good morning everyone,

First of all, I wanted to make it very clear that I checked if this question had been asked before and if it had been answered I would have solved the question.
I found this:
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scrapy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967930/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-scrapy)
That has been done for more than a year and the answers do not solve any problem related to me as the person who wrote it.

Something is wrong with my MacOs I think. When I wrote this code like on https://scrapy.org it doesn't work at all, after installing python3 and scrapy

Using

```
brew install python3
```

and for scrapy

```
pip install scrapy
```

Then I use the code from scrapy website:

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catégorie:Personnage_d%27animation']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('div#mw-pages div.mw-category li'):
            yield {'character': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}
```

And then I receive 2 type of messages:

If I run the code:

```
scrapy runspider myspider.py
```

I receive the message:

```
bash: scrapy: command not found
```

And if I open python3 and just write:

```
import scrapy
```

I receive this message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
```

Someone can help me fixing this, because i don't remember how can I do it I already uninstall both python and scrapy but nothing change.

then i used:

```
pip3 install scrapy
```

As DavidG told me told try

but I receive this message:

```
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

So after a few more searches, I just tried reinstalling Python3, so I used:

```
brew install python3
```

so I wrote:

```
pip3 --version
```

and showed this:

```
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Next:

```
scrapy --version
```

and received:

```
Scrapy 1.5.1 - no active project
```

so I tried to use the command again:

```
scrapy runspider myspider.py
```

and received this:

```
2018-07-18 20:11:49 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-07-18 20:11:49 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.3.0, libxml2 2.9.4, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0,w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 29 2018, 20:13:13) - [Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.3, Platform Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-07-18 20:11:49 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/runspider.py", line 88, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spidercls, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 170, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 198, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 203, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/telnet.py", line 12, in <module>
    from twisted.conch import manhole, telnet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/conch/manhole.py", line 154
    def write(self, data, async=False):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Can someone tell me what's going on and how to correct it?**

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of Python installed?

Comment: Are you sure you are installing `scrapy` for python 3.6?

Comment: Try `pip3 install scrapy`?

Comment: @DavidG look the update of my question

Comment: The word `async` became a reserved keyword in Python 3.7. The code is for Python 3 <= 3.6.

Comment: @phd I don't understood what you mean by that on my question.

Comment: @JérémyDATRINDADE The @phd poster is saying that the specifications of Python 3.7 have changed such that `async` is a reserved keyword, like `if`, `elif`, and `def`, and can't be used as a variable name. The code violates this and a syntax error is thrown. Try using `conda` (which I believe everyone who progams in python should be using anyway) and set the python version to, probably, 2.7.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston ah now I found it on the last code, but the problem is the async is not even wrote on my code but yes on python lib, so what can I do?

Comment: If you follow the Traceback, when you try to import `scrapy`, it tries to import `conch`. This is where it fails. Short of editing the `conch` sourcecode yourself, what this means is that effectively your version of Python is too new to import `scrapy`. Therefore, you need to use this with an earlier version of Python. Again, I recommend using conda for this, as it allows you to switch between any arbitrary version of Python very easily.

Answer (score 0):

So after the help and explanation of:

> @DavidG
>
> @phd
>
> @DanielR.Livingston

I figured it was not a problem with my computer, but it was all a compatibility issue.
It does not solve my problem, because this was an exercise I found in a MOOC, but since it has been done for some time it does not work in the same way, but at least I can move on to a different course since I can not do more anything with the scrapy.

Thank you all